# Unload module event handling in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, event-handling, air

I am developing an AIR app. In the main app I have a module loader 'mainModuleLoader'. I am creating modules as separate mxml files using the `<mx:Module>` tag. And I am loading such a module in mainModuleLoader dynamically using actionscript. Everything works fine.

For the module which I am creating as mxml files, I would like to know how to add an unload event handler. So that, whenever I call mainModuleLoader.unload(), the unload event hander is triggered from inside the module.mxml. I have tried the following without any success.

```
<mx:Module creatingComplete="init()" unload="unloadHandler()"/>
<mx:Module creatingComplete="init()" remove="unloadHandler()"/>
```

The problem with the second statement above is that it triggers the unloadHandler even if some child is removed inside the module. I have also tried to add the following in the action script.

```
private function init()
{
  this.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.UNLOAD, unloadHandler);
}
```

But, it doesn't trigger on unloading the module. Kindly let me know if I am going wrong somewhere or if there is any other method to attach the event handlers.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are part-way there with the remove; just check that `event.target` is the module before doing your work. It'll ignore the other ones then.

Comment: Thanks Gregor!! This one resolves my issue. :) in the remove handler i am simply using if(!(evt.target is myModule)) return;

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to handle the `unload` event of your `mainModuleLoader`:

```
<mx:ModuleLoader id="mainModuleLoader" unload="unloadHandler()"/>
```

Comment: Hey Splash, I cannot do that as different modules will have different unload functions defined internally. Some modules might not have unload functions also. So, I thought it's better for the module to call its own unload handlers if it has one.

Comment: @Goje87, I cannot find that `Module` has an `unload` event.